# Is there a more elegant way to specify multiple one to many relations of same nature?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having trouble trying to create the following entities relations. My code has the classes `Shop` and `Person`, and both have multiple `Phones`. My first implementation was something like this:

```
public class Person {
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones;
}

public class Shop {
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones;
}

public class Phone {
  public int Id;
  public string AreaCode;
  public string Number;

  public int? ShopId;
  public virtual Shop Shop;

  public int? PersonId;
  public virtual Person Person;
}
```

and the model builder like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
  .HasMany(p => p.Phones)
  .WithOptional(p => p.Person)
  .HasForeignKey(p => p.PersonId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>()
  .HasMany(p => p.Phones)
  .WithOptional(p => p.Shop)
  .HasForeignKey(p => p.ShopId);
```

My doubt here is: can I model it or change anything in my classes so when I'm handling the phones I don't have to keep checking if they are related to a `Shop` or a `Person`?

Comment: Can you please add what you are trying to do that requires you to check if you are dealing with a `Person` or a `Shop`?

Comment: Can phones coincide? For example, one person can have a work phone and the same phone can be "pinned" as shop number.

Comment: @Miamy Yes they can, but the way it's running today there would be two rows for each relation.

Comment: @npinti I use the phone data to send text messages, and depending on which the message should be different

Comment: The way I would do it, would be to have a method in `Person` and a method in `Shop` whose task was to send messages. That way, you will be delegating the creation and transmission to the entities that **know** what messages needs to be created.

Comment: Sound like a Need of **multiple inheritance**. If it's so, you have to know, that this is not possible in c#, but there are some workarounds using interfaces. Maybe `public interface IHavePhones { public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones; }. But I think this is much too easy here. So look there [Simulated Multiple Inheritance Pattern for C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10072/Simulated-Multiple-Inheritance-Pattern-for-C)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the next scheme:

```
public class Owner
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones;
  public abstract SendMessage(Phone phone);
}

public class Person : Owner 
{
  public override SendMessage(Phone phone)
  {
   ...
  }

}
public class Shop : Owner 
{
  public override SendMessage(Phone phone)
  {
   ...
  }
}

public class Phone {
  public int Id;
  public string AreaCode;
  public string Number;

  public int? OwnerId;
  public virtual Owner Owner;
}
```

So you haven't two entities with duplicating fields and, as npinti mentioned, you delegate messaging function to the corresponding entity.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little bit more context to my comment, the way I would go about it (with the information currently at hand) would be as follows:

1. I would create an interface, `IMessageSender`, which has 1 method: `SendMessage(Phone destination)`.
2. Have the `Shop` and `Person` class implement that interface. In the implementation of the method you would then have your logic which, from the comments, should differ from `Person` and `Shop`.
3. In the location where you want to send the message, simply iterate over the object and invoke `SendMessage`. This will, in turn, delegate the logic of the construction of the message to the appropriate class.